# How to setup 404 view correctly in Angular 4 while using UI router and lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I'm currently trying to setup 404 redirection for invalid paths in my Angular 4 application, which uses UI Router module https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/

Following are the states
**States mentioned in App.module.ts**

```js
export const routes = [
  { name: 'home', url:'/', component: HomeComponent },
  { name: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { name: 'detail.**', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule' },
  { name: 'barrel.**', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule' },
  { name: 'chartingtool', 
    url: '/:clientName/charting/:langCode/:template/', 
    component: ChartingComponent 
  },
  { name: '**', component: NoContentComponent }
];
```

```html
<a uiSref="home" uiSrefActive="active">
        Home
      </a>
      <a uiSref="detail" uiSrefActive="active">
        Detail
      </a>
      <a uiSref="barrel" uiSrefActive="active">
        Barrel
      </a>
      <a uiSref="about" uiSrefActive="active">
        About
      </a>
       <a uiSref="david" uiSrefActive="active">
        Invalid
      </a>
```

**States mentioned in Lazy loaded module (detail.module.ts)**

```js
export const STATES = [
  { name: 'detail', component: DetailComponent },
  { name: 'child-detail.**', loadChildren: './+child-detail#ChildDetailModule' }
];
```

```html
 <a uiSref="child-detail">
        Child Detail<!-- Leads to 404 -->
      </a>
```

**Issue:**

When I click on a link with `uiSref="child-detail"` in `detail.component.html`, UI router takes me 404 instead of lazy loaded module `child-detail`

I suspect that the issue is caused because 404 handling using `'**'` is added to list of states from main `app.module` as 7th rule, so subsequent rules/states that are added from the lazy loaded child modules are skipped/not processed.

Is there anyway to add a route with a low precedence / priority i.e., executed as last rule ? so that the routes from child modules are moved up in the list & validated.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: You can use this repo that has lazy loading in place https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter (But the router should be replaced with UI router)